# How to check any one of table cell's prop disable true or false in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a row by clicking the addNewRow button, I validate all input cell of that's row and after that, I click "CompletedBtn" and the row will disable.
but when I want to edit the specific row, when I click editBtn I want to check if any one of cell's prop("disable", false) or not in the entire table. if I get false, then I don't provide to edit row before complete another row that is property("disable", false).
How Can I find it?

Comment: like as 
function getRowCompletedStatus() {
       var openCell = $("#itemsListTable").find(".ExpenseItemId")"XXX disable or 
   not"; // finding code here

    if (openCell != undefined && openCell != "") {
  //if any cell found, then cell completed status=false
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
   }

Comment: 1) don't post code in comments. Put it in the question. 2) only form elements can be "disabled" so your question is nonsense as a table row (`<tr>`) can not have an attribute disabled.

Comment: table tr contain multiple input fields,  the disable's input fields enable when form post and must be after completed table. so why Can't have an attr disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have something like

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td disable="false">content</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

You could count disabled cells by doing

```
$("table#mytable tr td[disable='false']").size()
```

The CSS selector depends on you =)